# Is it possible to set host in fluentd s3_output

Tags: amazon-s3, output, fluentd

Is it possible to set somehow %{host} (not %{hostmane}: it is point to local fluentd server) in the fluentd S3 path like:

`s3://logs/2018/07/10/web01/misc-20180710-07_1.gz`

host is one of the message field `"host":"ip-10-78-46-14"`

```
<match ** >
  @type s3
  s3_bucket logs
  s3_region us-west-2
  path %Y/%m/%d
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d-%H
  s3_object_key_format %{path}/%{host}/misc-%{time_slice}_%{index}.%{file_extension}
  include_timestamp true
  <buffer host,tag,time>
    @type             file
    path              /buffers/s3/infra/misc/
    timekey           1h   # 1 hour partition
    timekey_wait      10m
    timekey_use_utc   true   # use utc
    chunk_limit_size  256m
  </buffer>

  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
</match>
```

This config is not working...

Thank you,
AP

Comment: what is your source for the fluent conf?. forward?

Comment: I have a couple of sources: forward, Secure forward and syslog

Comment: Did you try https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/filter_record_transformer or fluent-plugin-record-modifier for extracting the host from message field?. I think something like `host ${record["host"]}` . if my understanding is wrong, please provide some more info on how your incoming message looks like.